# running Node.js and Next.js application on windows server (IIS)

Tags: node.js, iis, next.js, windows-server, nodejs-server

I have a node.js application (only for api's on port 5000) and a next.js application (for users on port 3000) and I have to run it on windows server, I tried reverse proxy with IIS and I could run it but there is an issue with session and cookies, I believe IIS wont pass the cookie and session correctly to the user or the server and I get a weird UI like showing the login page but also the dashboard, or logging out but still navigation and using the app, I tries these configurations for the apps: 
API (node.js) `web.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="api" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5000/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Website (next.js) `web.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="web" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:3000/{R:0}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and this is the IIS sites:
[image: IIS sites]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem had something with IIS memory cashing duration, so I changed it from 60 to 1 and it fixed the problem, still I believe there could be a better solution but that is what I did for now.

these are the steps to do it:

1. in IIS select the server (probably named after you computer/server name).
2. go to `Application Request Routing Cache` page.
3. go to `Server Proxy Settings` via right side panel.
4. from `Cache Sttings` change `Memory cache duration (seconds)` to `1`

Comment: @YurongDai i have to wait a little more to accept it

Comment: We faced the same problem and came to the same conclusion to change the Memory cache duration to 0. The other "weird" solution we found without changing the memory size is to add "conditions" section in Url Rewrite rule in web.config....

Comment: @zhanke IIS is really strange, i highly recommend using NGINX